# Can human resource managers find out about my Stack overflow profile through my Developer Story?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, reputation, profile-page, privacy

If a human resource manager looking for a developer finds my Developer Story, Can this person find out about my StackOverflow profile and see my questions and answers and reputation?
I am concerned because I think there might be cases in which some companies would choose one developer instead of another based on this. Can you hide this information to them?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of SO Jobs to show off with your SO profile? Why is it a problem when companies use that to pre-screen candidates?

Answer (score 9):

There are several methods that others can link your Developer Story to your Stack Overflow account:

### 1) By including Stack Overflow as a site you want to display

If you select Stack Overflow to be displayed on your profile like this,

> [image]

there will be a clickable link to your profile in the developer story:

> [image]

### 2) By enabling your developer story profile tab, and sharing the developer story tab instead of the custom developer story link

There are two developer story links:

1. first with your profile tabs, e.g.: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/584192`
2. a customisable story only link, e.g.: `https://stackoverflow.com/story/samliew`

If the first link is enabled, and you share this link, others can simply click on the "Profile" tab to get to your Stack Overflow profile:

> [image]

In the "Developer Story preferences" settings page, you should hide your developer story tab, so that the first link is disabled to others:

> [image]

On the same settings page, you then need to enable the custom developer story link if you still want to share your developer story with others:

> [image]

### 3) By not disabling your developer story tab, and adding a company on your timeline with a link to their website.

If the first link is enabled, and you add a company link to your profile like this:

> [image]

The resulting company stub page will display the first link (developer story with profile tab):

> [image]

E.g.: If not private, links to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/584192` (instead of `https://stackoverflow.com/story/samliew`) if you didn't set it to private. If your first link is private, it just shows "Private user".

> [image]

### 4) By adding featured Stack Overflow posts that you have asked/answered in your developer story timeline

It's obvious that your posts link to your profile, so don't add them.

> [image]

### 5) By having a unique profile image that can be Google image reverse-searched for, linking to your Stack Overflow (and other website) accounts.